# Consultar un Json y guardarlo en una base de datos

Tags: android

Estoy creando un proyecto en android, tengo un `editText` y boton, ya les di una función, pero quiero que me realize una consulta más al web service y automaticamente me guarde en una base de datos lo que me duvuelve ese `JSON`.

mi base de datos, lo que me devuelve, quiero que me lo guarde en la tabla `dtusuario`

```
public class conexionSQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    final String CREAR_TABLA_CONFIGURACION="CREATE TABLE configuracion (valor VARCHAR(100))";
    final String CREAR_TABLA_DTUSUARIO="CREATE TABLE dtusuario(IDUSUARIO INTEGER primary key, CLAVE TEXT," +
            "NOMBRE VARCHAR(100), RUTA VARCHAR(100), ALMACEN_ID VARCHAR(100), VALIDA_INVENARIO_VENTAS VARCHAR(100)," +
            "USAQR VARHCAR(100),MODVENAS VARCHAR(100),MODCOBRANZA VARCHAR(100), DATOS VARCHAR(100)" +
            ",GPS VARCHAR(100),ABRIRCAJA VARCHAR(100), PCOBRANZA VARCHAR(100), PVENTA VARCHAR(100)," +
            "PPEDIDO VARCHAR(100), PCOTIZACION VARCHAR(100), MODPEDIDOS VARCHAR(100)," +
            "MODPRECIO VARCHAR(100), VALIDACAJA VARCHAR(100), FACTURA VARCHAR(100), PDEVOLUCIONES VARHCAR(100)," +
            "LIMITE_CREDITO VARCHAR(100), PRECIO_EMPRESA VARCHAR(1000), MOD_DESCUENTO VARCHAR(100)," +
            "ALTACLIENTE VARCHAR(100), SIG_FOLIO VARCHAR(100))";

    public conexionSQLiteHelper( Context context, String name,  SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREAR_TABLA_CONFIGURACION);
        db.execSQL(CREAR_TABLA_DTUSUARIO);

    }

 @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int versionAntigua, int versionNueva) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS configuracion ");
        onCreate(db);

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dtusuario ");
        onCreate(db);

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

El SQLiteOpenHelper  solo crear una instancia de la base de datos, para insertar registros debes realizar la consulta, al obtener los datos estableces una conexión a la base de datos y realizas la conversión, te recomiendo revisar Room.